# Oprofile error on android devices. oprofiled: too many events passed

Tags: android, oprofile

I use oprofile on my MDP. Android 4.3 userdebug version.

#opcontrol --setup

#oprofiled --vmlinux=/data/vmlinux --kernel-range=c00080ernel-range=c00080 --event=CPU_CYCLES

oprofiled: too many events passed.

# opcontrol --status
Driver directory: /dev/oprofile

Session directory: /data/oprofile

Counter 0:
    name: CPU_CYCLES
    count: 150000
Counter 1:
    name: CPU_CYCLES
    count: 150000
Counter 2 disabled

oprofiled is not running

But I just specify one event. Why oprofiled say "too many events passed"

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

If you look into the source file at [oprofile source](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~la5/oprofile/d9/da3/opd__events_8c_source.html)

and search for the error, you will see that c* is not getting empty forcing the code to throw the error.

Remove that if block and it worked for me.